# Maatwebsite/Excel Exporting Error

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.4 and I want to export a record to a excel file but I got this error

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 1332 and defined

and here is my code:

```html
   $export = Student::all();
    Excel::create('Export Excel',function($excel) use($export){
        $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) use($export){
            $sheet->fromArray($export);

        });
    })->download('xlsx');
```

```
   $export = Student::all();
Excel::create('Export Excel',function($excel) use($export){
    $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) use($export){
        $sheet->fromArray($export);

    });
})->download('xlsx');
```

Comment: What is the content of your code at line 1332?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you have a model named "Excel" that makes the problem.

Just make an alias for "Maatwebsite/Excel" when you imported :

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel as MaatExcel;
```

Answer (score 1):

`$export` is an Eloquent collection and you are using the `fromArray` method so it expects an array.

You can do two things:

1. Convert your Eloquent collection to an array:

`$sheet->fromArray($export->toArray());`

2. Use the `fromModel` method that accepts an Eloquent collection:

`$sheet->fromModel($export);`